# Modifying Reverse DNS GoDaddy

Tags: domain-name-system, email

I have a server that is purchased from Rackspace, then we have the domain and emails from GoDaddy. I'm currently having an issue where `mxtoolbox.com` is showing that the reverse DNS does not match my SMTP Banner.

Now, I'm sure I've set up my TXT records correctly for spf records and lookups. I was wondering if there is something I need to change or add in the spf record. I know GoDaddy is the one that sets the address up in the background, but there has to be a way to get the SMTP banner to match up with the reverse DNS.

Comment: It would help if you told us what OS you're using, what mail server you're using, what you've tried to do to change your SMTP banner, and what you think the problem might be.

Comment: Reverse DNS is set up by your server provider, that is Rackspace.

Comment: Well it's a Linux (Fedora) server for the website but the email server is housed and managed by GoDaddy, I have no access to it. Thanks Tero Kilkanen, I will reach out to Rackspace to get that information from them.

Comment: I am confused is your mail being sent from your server, or being sent via some kind of relay through Godaddy, or through Godaddy only.

Comment: Well, it is being sent through a relay in GoDaddy. I'm using Google email server but all of the spf and dns records are entered in and altered in GoDaddy DNS Manager.